# How many ways can you arrange $2$ blue beads, $1$ green bead, $1$ red bead, and $1$ yellow bead in a circle?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

> How many ways can you arrange $2$ blue beads, $1$ green bead, $1$ red bead, and $1$ yellow bead in a circle?

Which of the following would the answer be and why is the other one wrong?? 
$$3!=6\;\text{or}\;\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12$$

Comment: It's only six beads...why not write out all the cases by hand?

Comment: Because I want to know why the other "solution" is incorrect. Also, it's only 5 beads

Comment: At a guess, the question is whether reflection symmetry counts or not.  For a necklace, which can be flipped over, I'd say that two arrangements that differ by reflection coincided.

Comment: To be clearer:  does $YBBGR$ coincide with $YRGBB$ or not?   At a dinner table, I'd say no.  It matters who is on my left and who is on my right.  For a necklace (which I assume is the case, given the beads) I would say yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. $\!$

Comment: For counting the number of circles (*not necklaces*), put the yellow bead down at some arbitrary spot in the circle.  Use this as a point of reference.  Pick which two spaces out of the remaining $4$ are used by the blue beads.  Then pick whether the red occurs before or after the green bead clockwise from the yellow bead.  There are $6\cdot 2=12$ ways to do this.

Comment: I thought a combinatorial [necklace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) was equivalent through rotation but *not* reflection. Using this definition, the number of necklaces here is the coefficient of $b^2gry$ in [Pólya's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pólya_enumeration_theorem) formula: $$P_G=\frac{1}{5}\left(4(b^5+g^5+r^5+y^5)+(b+g+r+y)^5\right)$$ giving $\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{5!}{2!1!^3}=12$. Or note that blue beads can have minimum separation of 1 or 2 spaces, the remaining beads can be placed in $3!$ ways, so $2\cdot 3!=12$. Or use @JMoravitz's reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would compute the answer as

$$2(3+3)=12$$

Here's the idea:  First place the Red, Green, and Yellow beads on the circle; there are $2$ ways to do this.  Then place the two Blue beads either *together* between two beads already on the circle, or *apart*; in either case there are $3$ ways to place the Blue beads.

If you consider mirror images as identical, then there is only $1$ way to place the Red, Green, and Yellow beads in the first step, which gives the answer $3+3=6$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\frac {4!}{2!}$. The reason is this:

Suppose your 2 blue beads are distinct. Then how many ways are there to arrange these 5 beads in a circle? Well, by the formula it's $\frac {5!}{5}=4!$. But because earlier on we assumed our blue beads are distinct, we permuted them in $2!$ ways. Hence, we need to reverse this order and therefore, the answer is $\frac {4!}{2!}$. Hope it helps!